# How do I generate this type of plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to create a 'blob' type plot in Matlab like as shown in the link below.

[image: Image link]

Is this type of plot possible in Matlab? I was considering contour plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reach a similar result by using a spline interpolation. In this example I duplicate the values of x1 and y1 vector to avoid to get a discontinuity on the interpolated shape. Unfortunately the `fill` function from Octave can't deal with transparency, so you're free to adapt this code to add this option.

```
n = 1000;                                       % # of interpolation points.
p = 5                                           % # of label
lab = {'text1','text2','text3','text4','text5'} % label

theta  = linspace(0,2*pi-(2*pi)/p,p); % The angle
thetal = [theta(1),theta(end:-1:2)];  % Theta for placement of labels
rho    = [0.65 0.8 0.7 0.9 1]         % The spider graph values

[x1,y1] = pol2cart(theta,rho)

x1 = repmat(x1,1,10); 
y1 = repmat(y1,1,10);
```

As you can see in the graph below if I do not replicate the x1 and y1 vector I will obtain some discontinuity when I compute the interpolation:

[image]

```
t = [0,cumsum(sqrt(diff(x1).^2+diff(y1).^2))]; %cumsum(euclidian distance) => t(end) = perimeter.
ti = linspace(0,t(end),n);
x = interp1(t,x1,ti,'spline');
y = interp1(t,y1,ti,'spline');

%We plot the interpolated shape
fill(x(round(0.5*n):round(0.6*n)),y(round(0.5*n):round(0.6*n)),[0.2,0.2,0.2]) %you need to start to fill your interpolated shape at another point than the first and last point if you want to avoid a discontinuity.

hold on

%Then we plot a circle and some other stuff
set(gca,'Color',[0.6 0.6 0.6]);
%plot(0,0,'bo')
plot(x1,y1,'o','Color',[0.4,0.4,0.4],'MarkerSize',3,'MarkerFaceColor','auto')
plot(sin(0:0.1:2*pi+0.1),cos(0:0.1:2*pi+0.1),'Color',[0.4,0.4,0.4],'linewidth',3)
for i = 1:p
    plot([0,sin(theta(i)+pi/2)],[0,cos(theta(i)+pi/2)],'Color',[0.4,0.4,0.4],'linewidth',3);
    h(i) = text(sin(theta(i)+pi/2),cos(theta(i)+pi/2),lab{i});
    set(h(i), 'rotation', rad2deg(thetal(i))-90,'HorizontalAlignment','center','VerticalAlignment','bottom')
end
ylim([-1.2,1.2])
xlim([-1.2,1.2])
axis equal
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer my question :)

Comment: Hello, I get the general sense of your code but some parts are quite vague. Could you pls briefly explain them pls? Why do we have to replicate the x1, y1 matrices 10 times? Plus, how does the differenced cumulative sum of euclidean distance give you perimeter? Is there any theorem I am missing there? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, you can't interpolate non monotonic data, so I force the interpolation to be monotonic by using the`t` vector which correspond to the length of the polygon created by your 5 points. And look at the first figure in my answer,  the thin line represent the interpolation shape if x1 and y1 were not replicated. But if we replicate the x1 and y1 vector the interpolation tend to converge towards a regular shape (thick line)

Comment: It could be replicated 5,6,7... or 10 times, it doesn't matter, we only want to obtain a nice regular rounded shape without ugly angle.